# Order of a homomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f: G \to H$ be a homomorphism of groups. Assume that $a\in G$ and $\operatorname{ord}(a)=n$. Prove that the order of $f(a)$ is a divisor of $n$.

I know that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $$|G|=|H|\cdot|\text{distinct cosets of $H$}|$$ so $|H|$ must be divisor of $|G|$, but I don't understand how to apply that logic to homomorphisms (or if that will even work).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
$$ \left( f(a) \right)^n=f(a^n)=f(e)=e \,.$$

You don
't need to calculate the order of $f$, you need to calculate the order of $f(a)$ which is an element in $H$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: in order for $f$ to be a homomorphism, it has to respect powers of $a$. Look at $f(a^{|f(a)|})$.

$|f(a)| = \operatorname{ord}(f(a))$ if you are unfamiliar with the notation.

Edit: I actually believe N.S.'s hint is better. Hopefully mine will get you thinking, anyway.